# Exchanging small chunks of data over socket in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sockets

I need to receive small portions of data (100-300 bytes) from the server.
To do this, I use a BufferedInputStream with bufferSize = 256. Sometimes the data arrives with a very long delay.

```
socket.getInputStream().buffered(256)?.use {inputStream->
            do {
                val byteArray = ByteArray(4096)
                var count = -1
                try {
                    count = inputStream.read(byteArray)
                }
                catch (ex : Exception){
                    ex.printStackTrace()
                }
                if(count==-1){
                    break
                }
            }while (count>-1 && isConnected())
        }
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use a buffer size with buffered input stream. Instead if you want to read 233 bytes then declare a byte buffer of that much bytes and read until full. You could alse use  `count = inputStream.read(byteArray, 0, 233)`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. I set

```
socket?.receiveBufferSize = 512
socket?.tcpNoDelay = true
```